# Is it good to call a manager/service class from within an object method?

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I have an object, VirtualMachine, it has a Reboot() method, PowerOn() methods etc.

These methods need to call an external API which I proxy via a management class' static methods to do the work against the external API. Is it good practice to call these manager classes from within an instance of a class?

So for example:

```
private void Reboot()
{
     VirtualMachineManager.Reboot(this.Name);
}
```

Is it ok to use manager classes like this within OOP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't see any problem with this until `VirtualMachineManager` class only *executes* an action and not stores an information in itself. *Usually* static method is a sign/intent of stateless execution. It may change a state of an object passed like a parameter, but *usually* didn't store some persistent information. So for me it's good.

All described here is a subject of discussion and matter of particular case (application domain). Everyone is free to choose an architecture he prefers, I just described general intent that your class consumer gets when see a `static` method declaration/execution.

Good luck.